# What is the easiest and safest way to discharge a computer power supply?

Tags: power-supply, discharge

I have a couple of old computer PSU that I want to take apart to see how much copper is in them. Want to safely discharge them before I do though. Wondering what exactly is the process to do so?

I'm relatively certain the transformers don't have much in the way of copper, but I want to see exactly what type of transformers they have.

Comment: If these weren't in use for a while, there would be nothing to discharge.

Comment: really, I was told that a psu can hold power for a while

Comment: Depends on the "while" duration :)

Comment: maybe try to discharge just to be safe then

Comment: There is no legal requirement on anything not user touchable, but you’ll be hard pressed to find any computer power supply with any harmful voltage after one minute. Don’t bet your life on it though! I’ve zapped myself with 400 V DC off the PFC stage once. A prototype board made by yours truly.

Answer (score 1):

The standard practice is to take a screwdriver and short out the terminals to ground with the unit unplugged. However after about 30 seconds this is unnecessary because power supplies that are UL and IEC certified or built to discharge to a safe voltage after the amount of time.

If the supplies been sitting there fora long time it's unlikely that there's any dangerous voltage, because capacitors have internal resistance leakage and self discharge over time.